# React multiple input (array of inputs) not working

Tags: reactjs

So I'm attempting to render multiple input fields with React.
Everything looks fine until I remove an item. Always the last item is being "removed". If you want to try my code, write "A" in input field 1, "B" in 2, "C" in 3 and remove "B". You'll notice that you have removed "C" instead.

I have tried both `value` and `defaultValue` for `input` to no avail. I have also tried giving a name to the input. I think I am missing a key point here.

Any recommendations?

```
var MultiInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    value = this.props.value
    // force at least one element
    if (!value || value == '') {
      value = [ null ]
    }

    return {
      value: value
    }
  },
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
    }
  },
  add_more: function() {
    new_val = this.state.value.concat([])
    new_val.push(null)
    this.setState({ value: new_val })
  },
  remove_item: function(e, i) {
    new_state = this.state.value.concat([])
    new_state.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({ value: new_state })
  },
  render: function() {
    me = this

    // console.log(this.state.value)
    lines = this.state.value.map( function(e, i) {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <input value={e} />
          <button onClick={me.remove_item} >X</button>
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        {lines}
        <button onClick={this.add_more}>Add More</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

To start, you shouldn't use the array index as the key when rendering in an array:

```
lines = this.state.value.map( function(e, i) {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <input value={e} />
      <button onClick={me.remove_item} >X</button>
    </div>
  )
})
```

The first time through, `["A", "B", "C"]` renders:

```
    <div key={0}>
      ...
    </div>
    <div key={1}>
      ...
    </div>
    <div key={2}>
      ...
    </div>
```

Then, the second time, once you've removed `"B"` and left `["A", "C"]`, it renders the following:

```
    <div key={0}>
      ...
    </div>
    <div key={1}>
      ...
    </div>
```

So, when you removed item at index `1`, the item previous at index `2` moves to index `1`. You'll want to use some unique value that doesn't change when the position in the array changes.

Second, you should use the empty string instead of `null` for initialization, and then you'll see that you can't type anything in your inputs. That's because `value` ensures that an input's value is always whatever you pass it; you'd have to attach an `onChange` handler to allow the value to be edited.

Changing to `defaultValue` allows you to type in the box, but when you type, the string in `this.state.value` doesn't get updated--you'd still need an `onChange` handler.

Finally, your button has an `onClick` of `this.remove_item`, but your `remove_item` method seems to take the event and index as parameters. However, React will not pass the current index to `remove_item`; you would need to create a new function that passes the correct params:

```
onClick={me.remove_item.bind(null, i)}
```

That said, you really shouldn't call `Function#bind` inside `render` as you'll create new functions every time it runs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I'm updating my question with code that works =)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code**

@BinaryMuse clearly explains why my code above doesn't work: by removing an item from the array and render is called again, the items change position and apparently React's algorithm picks the "wrong changes" because the key we're providing has changed.

I think the simplest way around this is to not remove the item from the array but rather replace it with `undefined`. The array would keep growing with this solution but I don't think the number of actions would slow this down too much, especially that generating a unique id that doesn't change might involve storing this ID as well.

Here's the working code: (If you wish to optimize it, please check @BinaryMuse's suggestions in the accepted answer. My `MultInput` uses a custom `Input` component that is too large to paste here =) )

```
var MultiInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    value = this.props.value
    if (!value || value == '') {
      value = [ '' ]
    }

    return {
      value: value
    }
  },
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
    }
  },
  add_more: function() {
    new_val = this.state.value.concat([])
    new_val.push('')
    this.setState({ value: new_val })
  },
  remove_item: function(i,e) {
    new_state = this.state.value.concat([])
    new_state[i] = undefined
    this.setState({ value: new_state })
  },
  render: function() {
    me = this

    lines = this.state.value.map( function(e, i) {
      if (e == undefined) {
        return null
      }

      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <input defaultValue={e} />
          <button onClick={me.remove_item.bind(null, i)} >X</button>
        </div>
      )
    }).filter( function(e) {
      return e != undefined
    })

    return (
      <div>
        {lines}
        <button onClick={this.add_more}>Add More</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```